# Java regex data modification

Tags: java, regex

I'm working on an automated data identification program. The program is supposed to read through a text file and modify certain lines. For a simplified example, if a directory is "Folder/SubfolderZ/index.html", I would want it changed to "Folder/SubfolderX/index.html". "Folder" contains various subfolders.
The exact problem is a little more complicated, but follows the same logic.

(edited)

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<dt><li><a href=\"New folder/(1Visual Index|2Basic Charts|3Techniques, Interaction & Animation|4other|check)/(wimbledon_2012|azimuthal_projections|.)/index.html\" target=\"content\">.</a></li>");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("<dt><li><a href=\"New folder/1Visual Index/box_plot/index.html\" target=\"content\">Box Plot</a>");
```

The code above is not giving a match. I'll admit I don't have much experience with regular expressions. Could someone point out why the code is not working properly??

Comment: The pattern starts off with `<dd><a...` and it is trying to match `<dt><li><a...`.  I don't think this example should match, can you give us sample input and expected output?

Comment: Also while `1Visual Index` will match `box_plot` will not. The entire regular expression must match not just parts of it.

Comment: @Sam
I added an edit.

Comment: @BevynQ
Souldn't the . meta character allow box_plot to match?

Comment: . will match any single character not a group of characters

Answer (score 0):

Only check what you want to find.
Try:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<a href=\"New folder/(1Visual Index|2Basic Charts|3Techniques, Interaction & Animation|4other|check)/([^/]++)/index\.html\" target=\"content\">");
```